# Who actually is the 'Devil King Of the Sixth Heaven'?

Tags: life

I want to ask who is the devil king of the sixth heaven actually is and i also want to ask what happen to the people who suicide in buddhism ?

Answer (score 1):

Mara is the leader of a faction in the [6th heaven](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html):

> **(11)** Devas Wielding Power over the Creation of Others (*paranimmita-vasavatti deva*)
>
> These devas enjoy sense pleasures created by others for them. Mara, the personification of delusion and desire, lives here.

He's neither the king there nor the king of all demons. Demons mostly belong to the [first heaven](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html). That faction is just opposed to anyone trying to attain enlightenment or lead others to enlightenment.

People who commit suicide usually have an unskillful state of mind in their final moments. So it is most likely that they end up in a lower realm. But there can be rare exceptions.

Comment: I marked you post down because it has no references to support the answer, therefore is merely opinion based. Regards

Comment: Added a reference. But why would you ask for a reference when you do not believe in other realms or life after death in any case? :)

Comment: A more detailed reference here -- [Sixth and highest heaven of the Desire Realm](http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/Sixth_and_highest_heaven_of_the_Desire_Realm) -- and more at [True Buddha Dharma-character Treasury - Mahesvara Buddha](http://tbsn.org/english2/news.php?id=479&classid=1) about Mara as opposition -- I can't say how reliable these references are, and, they're not Theravada.

Comment: Suicide reference?

Comment: Most of devaputtamāra appear in tipitaka. Even commentary explained just a little bit as "'pajāpatiṃ' (in mūlapariyāyasutta) means māro. One explained 'pajāpatiṃ means mahārājā, the leader of each deva group, but the great commentary already denied that explanation because mahārājā already included in 'deve' word, above. So māro means pajāpati in this sutta by leading of lives, pajā. Where is him? He is in the sixth heaven realm. Actually, there is vasavattirājā on that realm. One explained 'māro is the leader of his people in a part of that realm like a crown prince in colony'".

Comment: http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/attha_page.php?book=7&page=36&pages=1&edition=roman